# Как исправить ошибку преобразования?

Tags: c#, sql

Есть вот такой вот sql-запрос с параметрами:

```
sqlSelect =
        @"SELECT * FROM Автомобиль WHERE VIN_номер = '@VIN' OR Номер_заказа = '@Заказ' OR Номер_филиала = '@Филиал'";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = LAPTOP-KJLU9H2F\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = 'Автосалон'; Integrated Security = True");
        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sqlSelect;
        command.Parameters.Add("@VIN",SqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value = VIN.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Заказ", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Nomer_zakaza.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Филиал", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Nomer_filiala.Text;
```

При выполнении этого кода вылазит вот это:"Ошибка преобразования значения varchar "@Заказ" в тип данных int.
Вот если что характеристики таблицы, с которой работаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Используйте явное приведение типа значения `Nomer_zakaza.Text` к числовому. И уберите кавычки из текста запроса. То же и касательно филиала. И вообще - проверяйте, что там введено в полях. а не пихайте тупо в запрос.

Comment: Повторяю: уберите одинарные кавычки вокруг имён параметров в sql-запросе. И все `AddWithValue` замените на `Add`.

Comment: Все, теперь я окончательно разобрался. Единственное что, вот у меня есть три Textbox, и если во все три textbox вводить значения, то я получаю ожидаемый результат, а если один из этих трех textbox пустой, то и ничего не происходит, а хотелось бы, чтобы при любом количестве заполненных textbox sql-запрос срабатывал. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: @Lenz ссылки на неофициальные зеркала StackOverflow не приветствуются https://stackoverflow.com/q/3415582/12888024 Старайтесь давать ссылки на первоисточник, а не на зеркала с кучей рекламы.